# Angular JS using $http() get a response, with status 200, but data is null

Tags: angularjs

I'm using this angular code:

```
$http({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'json/test.json',
  responseType: "json"
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log('Success: ' + data);
  $scope.tests = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

the response is like this:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'aaaa',
  age: 20
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'bbbbb',
  age: 21
}]
```

In the console, it prints:

```
Success: null
```

how come it returns success, but data is null.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any different result if you remove the "responseType" setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might happen because `json` is not formatted properly. Try:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aaaa",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "bbbbb",
        "age": 21
    }
]
```

and use

```
$http.get("json/test.json").success(function (data) {
    console.log('success: ' + data)
});
```

or you may use your original code but without `responseType` as @DeborahK figured out:

```
$http({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'json/test.json'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log('Success: ' + data);
})
```

But anyway you would need to format your `json` properly, otherwise angular will raise parsing exception.

Comment: I tried them, none of them working. the error is something like: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: another error is:   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: I'm also having `SyntaxError: Unexpected token i` if I use your JSON. Try some some simple json e.g. `[{ "foo": "bar" }]`, restart node (or other server), clear caches, and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of AngularJS you are using, but assuming v1.6, then try this:

```
$http.get("json/test.json").then(function(response) {
    console.log('success: ' + response.data);
}).catch(function(response) {
    console.log('error: ' + response.data);
});
```