# AngularJS $http returning 200 ok, but fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

I'm trying to do a simple ajax request, and the response status is "200, ok", using the Postman I can validate my JSON, and looks fine, and the header is ok too ... but $http aways fail.
I try to put a very simple JSON and aways have the same result.
The solutions doesn't work for me

- [Ajax request returns 200 OK, but an error event is fired instead of success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success)
- [Angular JS using $http() get a response, with status 200, but data is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868062/angular-js-using-http-get-a-response-with-status-200-but-data-is-null)

My ANGUJAR JS request:

```
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/produto/')
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.info('success =)');
                console.info(response);
                // this callback will be called asynchronouslywhen the response is available

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                console.info('fail =(');
                console.info(response);
            });
```

My JSON result, but with a simple response like [] I had the same problem :

```
[{"id":1,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 13:23:49","updated_at":"2016-04-26 13:23:49"},{"id":2,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 13:24:25","updated_at":"2016-04-26 13:24:25"},{"id":3,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 13:24:46","updated_at":"2016-04-26 13:24:46"},{"id":4,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 13:25:16","updated_at":"2016-04-26 13:25:16"},{"id":5,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 13:28:06","updated_at":"2016-04-26 13:28:06"},{"id":6,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 18:05:15","updated_at":"2016-04-26 18:05:16"},{"id":7,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 18:52:42","updated_at":"2016-04-26 18:52:43"},{"id":8,"nome":"NOME UPD","doce":"1","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2016-04-26 20:29:43","updated_at":"2016-04-26 20:29:43"}]
```

Tanks a lot.

Comment: Could try the next syntax? http://jsbin.com/fofariziga/edit?js,output Just in case, please add the error response from the .catch block

Comment: The same... status = 0, data = null, statusText = ""

Comment: what is your server side route looks like?

Comment: I'm using in my own machine, the http://127.0.0.1:8000/produto is right

Comment: Your URL in the $http is produto/ try to change it by produto without the end slash

Comment: tanks, but still have the same result =\

Comment: in the postman works fine with or without the last slash

Comment: The request enters in the route of your server? Try doing $http.get('/producto').then... Just in case

Comment: No ... is localhost but is another application. The angularjs app run in the port 80

Comment: Which error are you getting? Did you inspect the request using Chrome Dev Tools or Firefox? Post the request message here, and the response, should help us to help you.

Comment: I don't have a error message, the result is empty, but the HTTP status of the request is 200.
Looks like the content is invalid, but the same content in a static file works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was with CORS access.
the server don't allow requests from my AngularJS application ...

I enable my apache to allow access

```
a2enmod headers
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

In the file, put inside the tag

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

And restart the apache

See. http://www.mechonomics.com/enabling-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-for-apache2-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Tanks

Comment: It worked well for me. The only difference was the default file in my Linux was 000-default.conf in that location.