# Angular 2 http post request getting null response but status code is 200

Tags: angular, http

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2765
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:169.172.68.223:9443
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/signon
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
```

Is anything related to *Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br* ?

Please let me know, how to fix this?

Comment: We cannot help with the above information, please check the rules how to ask question that we would have some more information and the ability to help. thanks.

Comment: When i hit request from Postman, it's working but not working code.

Comment: We need to see the code, we cannot help like this.. add a snipcode

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP Status Code 200 only means an 'OK' response. What it means is that your request has succeeded, a null response does not mean your request hasn't succeeded and that's why you can get a 200 response even if the response is null. The fact that the response returned is 'null' but that your response has succeeded could be due to a variety of reasons.

For instance, take a look at this question:
[Angular JS using $http() get a response, with status 200, but data is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868062/angular-js-using-http-get-a-response-with-status-200-but-data-is-null)